# how to call the coroutine methods/functions periodically after one minute

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, openweathermap

I'm trying to implement a weather app. So I need to make a call to the API every minute. So my API call function is a suspend function that gets called in a coroutine inside the mainActivity. How do I make a call for these coroutine methods every 60 seconds so that they can make an API call?

This is the bit from my mainActivity where I call the suspend functions. I am trying to call the methods inside GlobalScope after every minute.

```
val lat = location.latitude
val lon = location.longitude

val vmFactory = weatherVMFactory(application,appcontext,netwReq,lat.toString(),lon.toString())
val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this,vmFactory).get(weatherVM::class.java)

GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {

                        //THESE METHODS NEED TO BE CALLED EVERY MINUTE 

                        val wInfo = async { viewModel.otherData() }
                        setOtherData(wInfo.await())

                        val dInfo = async { viewModel.dailyData() }
                        setDailyData(dInfo.await())

                        val hInfo = async { viewModel.hourlyData() }
                        setHourlyData(hInfo.await())
}
```

This is my viewmodel Class just for reference:

```
package com.example.weatherapp

import android.app.Application
import android.content.Context
import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

class weatherVM(application: Application, appcon: Context, jQueue: Singleton, latitude: String, longitude: String) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val wRepo = WeatherRepo(appcon,jQueue,latitude,longitude)

    suspend fun otherData(): MutableLiveData<OtherInfo> {
        return wRepo.getOtherData()
    }

    suspend fun dailyData(): MutableLiveData<ArrayList<DailyInfo>> {
        return wRepo.getDailyData()
    }

    suspend fun hourlyData(): MutableLiveData<ArrayList<HourlyInfo>>{
        return wRepo.getHourlyData()
    }

}
```

One of the functions inside my Repository:

```
suspend fun getDailyData(): MutableLiveData<ArrayList<DailyInfo>> = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){                                         //suspend this function

        val tinfoArr = ArrayList<DailyInfo>()
        val jsonO = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,{

            val dailyArr = it.getJSONArray("daily")

            for (i in 1 until dailyArr.length()) {

                val dailyObj = dailyArr.getJSONObject(i)
                val daily = DailyInfo(dailyObj.getLong("dt"),dailyObj.getInt("humidity"),dailyObj.getJSONObject("temp").getInt("day"),dailyObj.getJSONObject("feels_like").getInt("day"))
                tinfoArr.add(daily)
            }
            dInfo.value = tinfoArr

        },{
            Toast.makeText(appCon,"Error fetching Daily Forecast",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        })

        jQueue.addToRequestQueue(jsonO)

        return@withContext dInfo
    }
```

Any ideas/suggestions as to making the suspend functions calls every minute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of an infinite loop and a `delay()` function to execute a function periodically. For example, if you want to execute `doSomething` every minute, you can do it like this:

```kotlin
viewModelScope.launch {
    while(true) {
        doSomething()
        delay(60_000) // delay 1 minute
    }
}
```

Also, you should never use **GlobalScope**. Instead, use scopes which are bound to some lifecycle i.e. which get cancelled automatically (like `lifecycleScope` or `viewModelScope`).

Comment: viewModelScope or lifecycleScope are not defined when I'm trying to replace them with GlobalScope. Any idea as to what changes I should make?

Comment: I suggest moving this logic to the viewModel. And from ViewModel, you can use something like a `LiveData` or `StateFlow` to update the UI.